# Jenkins How to show fail/pass on measurement plot plugin

Tags: xml, jenkins, junit, jenkins-plugins

I'm using measurement plot plugin recently. One of the issue I'm facing is that I can't show test failed result on measurement plot plugin. 
I've read the [introduction](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Measurement+Plots+Plugin) about the plugin on Jenkins. The documentation shows an example, and I've try it but still no result.
Please guide me to solve this problem.
Thank you in advance!(below is the code I've try to generate the fail test result but can't work.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites>
<testsuite name="package">
   <testcase name="case" time="0"/>
   <system-out>
    <standard-error>
    &lt;measurement&gt;&lt;name&gt;hi&lt;/name&gt;&lt;value&gt;16&lt;/value&gt;&lt;/measurement&gt;
    </standard-error> 
</testsuite>
```

Comment: The output XML is not [well-formed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document). The element _system-out_ is not closed, as is the root element.

Comment: @StefanHanke Thanks man, I've solved my question.